Restrictions of the map $z \mapsto z^2$ that are homeomorphisms
Let $\varphi(z) = z^2, |z| = 1$. Is it possible to find a perfect nowhere dense subset $E$ of the unit circle such that $\varphi(E) =E$ and the restriction of $\varphi$ on $E$ is a homeomorphism?
(There are many examples of $\varphi$-invariant perfect nowhere dense subsets of the unit circle, see e.g. the book of Hasselblatt and Katok, but so far I could not find such one that the restriction would be one-to one.)
